# How to add onclick events to Texture in libgdx android?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have two Textures, I need to add touch events for this Textures, How can I do this,

```
Texture up,down;

@Override
public void create () {
    up=new Texture("top_arrow.png");
    down=new Texture("down_arrow.png");
}

@Override
public void render() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [InputProcessor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) to process input from the user base on where the user clicks. A guide on this is shown [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Mouse%2C-touch-%26-keyboard)

Or my preferred method is to use scene2d and use a ImageButton which is explained in this [LibGDX simple button with image](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121115/libgdx-simple-button-with-image)

This code below is an example of a single button that changes image when clicked on:

```
package com.mygdx.gtest;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button.ButtonStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;

public class Test extends ApplicationAdapter{

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        //create images
        Pixmap pmap = new Pixmap(100,100,Format.RGBA4444);
        pmap.setColor(Color.RED);
        pmap.fill();
        Texture buttonUpRed = new Texture(pmap);
        pmap.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        pmap.fill();
        Texture buttonDownBlue = new Texture(pmap);
        pmap.dispose();

        //make button style (usually done with skin)
        ButtonStyle tbs = new ButtonStyle();
        tbs.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(buttonDownBlue));
        tbs.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(buttonUpRed));

        // make button
        Button btn = new Button(tbs);

        //make stage
        stage = new Stage();

        // ad button to layout table
        Table table = new Table();
        table.add(btn);

        //add table to stage
        stage.addActor(table);

        //set the stage to be the input processor so it responds to clicks
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did like  [link]https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121115/libgdx-simple-button-with-image .But how to set the position to a stage?

Comment: You can use layout components like Table, Stack , VerticalGroup etc. A nice description on how to use them as well as what they do is on the LibGdx wiki https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#layout

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Sprite` or `Image` instead of Texture for touch detection.

The [Sprite](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites#sprite) class describes both a texture region, the geometry where it will be drawn, and the color it will be drawn.

If you want to use scene2d you can use [Image](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#image), Image simply displays a drawable. The drawable can be a texture, texture region, ninepatch, sprite, etc.

You can detect touch in this way :

```
public class TouchSystem extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {

    private SpriteBatch batch;

    Texture up,down;
    Sprite upSprite,downSprite;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    Vector3 temp;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        temp=new Vector3();
        camera=new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        batch=new SpriteBatch();
        up=new Texture("top_arrow.png");
        down=new Texture("down_arrow.png");

        upSprite=new Sprite(up);

        downSprite=new Sprite(down);
        downSprite.setPosition(200,100);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        upSprite.draw(batch);
        downSprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

        up.dispose();
        down.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        super.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        temp.set(screenX,screenY,0);
        camera.unproject(temp);

        if(upSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(temp.x,temp.y))
            System.out.println("Touch on upSprite");

        if(downSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(temp.x,temp.y))
            System.out.println("Touch on downSprite");

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```